# Error: Object of type User is not JSON serializable while creating issue with jira-python

Tags: python, task, jira, python-jira

I'm new to both jira and python and I'm trying to create an issue through jira-python and got this error:

> TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable

I've tried to remove some fields but still I got the same error and have no idea what I did wrong. I am able to retrieve all those fields from an existing issue.

I know there is a lot of similar questions but none is really helpful

Here is my code:

```
 python
chapeauId='XXXXX'
jiraChapeau= jira.issue(chapeauId)
summary = "socle serveur pour le projet d'automatisation"
description ="Une description regroupant les paramètres du socle"
issueType="T-065"
priority='Mineur'
zoneReseau='XXXXXXX'
cPT= jiraChapeau.fields.reporter

 issueDict={ 
   'project': {'key': "AB-01"},
   'parent': chapeauId,
   'summary': summary,
   'description': description,
   'priority': priority,
   'issuetype': {'name':issueType},
   'customfield_13034': zoneReseau,
   'customfield_10490' : cPT,

}
newIssue=jira.create_issue(fields=issueDict)

TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're doing the authentication but not showing it? Here is an example on how to create an issue. My guess is your reporter value isn't working because that's the only user related thing I see. I'd check what value you get for jiraChapeau.fields.reporter. It might be more than than just an email. What is your 'customfield_10490'? Probably doesn't like whatever fields.reporter

```
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=(jira_username, jira_token), options 
= {'server':'https://'+jira_domain+'.atlassian.net'})

issue_dict = {
  'project' : {'key':'ITS'},
  'summary' : 'Store JIRA Backup',
  'assignee': {'name': 'user_email_address_goes_here'},
  'issuetype': {'name':'Service Request'},
  'description': 'Create and download the JIRA backup and store on S: Drive (until 
   another location for cloud storage backups is determined)',
  'components': [{'name': 'JIRA'}],
}
jira.create_issue(issue_dict)
```

Comment: You are probably right. 'customfield_10490' is for the project manager (chef de projet) and I realize I didn't need to specify it since the default value for that field was the parent project manager. I removed  'customfield_10490' : cPT and  'customfield_13034': zoneReseau, since the last one was throwing the same error and my code is working. I'm looking for another way to add it along with the date. Thanks a lot @guitarhero23